# Calendar webpart not available in the apps list in sharepoint 2016

Tags: web-part, 2016, calendar, edit

I have an on-premises Sharepoint 2016 installation. I am trying to add a Calendar webpart on a test page. But I cannot find it in the apps list.

[image: Webpart Apps list]

I added my calendar app in the site contents.
[image: Calendar App]

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: the apps for the page will only show the lists/libraries inside the same site.. so where have you added the calendar list? and where you are trying to add it as a webpart? are you at the same site?

Comment: Ah yes, I added in the main site and the page is in a sub-site. Thanks for the help

Comment: if you find my answer useful.please mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Noorul The App part inside the page will only show the lists and libraries at the same site.  you can not use App parts to show lists and libraries from other sites or other site collections